# Apex 5.1 : Escape Special Character Issue on Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

how to resolve "Escape Special character" Issue(as shown in pic) on Interactive Grid 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The Escape special characters attribute is available in the Security section of the property sheet for Display Only interactive grid columns. The Security section is only visible when "Show All" is selected on the property sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't add comments. Can you try for name column in your query something like:

```
utl_i18n.unescape_reference(Name)
```

for example:

```
select utl_i18n.unescape_reference('Classes &amp; Subjects') from dual
```

or

```
select utl_i18n.unescape_reference('Classes & Subjects') from dual
```

both returns

Classes & Subjects